# Secure FTP using Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, sftp

I currently have batch scripts on different servers that transfer a csv file to an FTP server at a different location. My script looks similar to this:

```
echo user ftp_user> ftpcmd.dat
echo password>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put c:\directory\%1-export-%date%.csv>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.MyFTPSite.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

If I wanted to require a secure transmission, is how would my script be updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, make sure you understand, if you need to use [Secure FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) (=FTPS, as per your text) or [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) (as per tag you have used).

Neither is supported by Windows command-line `ftp.exe`. As you have suggested, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/). It supports both FTPS and SFTP.

Using WinSCP, your batch file would look like (for SFTP):

```
echo open sftp://ftp_user:password@ftp.MyFTPSite.com -hostkey="..." >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put c:\directory\%1-export-%date%.csv >> ftpcmd.dat
echo exit >> ftpcmd.dat
winscp.com /script=ftpcmd.dat
del ftpcmd.dat
```

And the batch file:

```
winscp.com /log=ftpcmd.log /script=ftpcmd.dat /parameter %1 %date%
```

---

Though using all capabilities of WinSCP (particularly [providing commands directly on command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) and the [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp)), the batch file simplifies to:

```
winscp.com /log=ftpcmd.log /command ^
    "open sftp://ftp_user:password@ftp.MyFTPSite.com -hostkey=""...""" ^
    "put c:\directory\%1-export-%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%.csv" ^
    "exit"
```

For the purpose of `-hostkey` switch, see [verifying the host key in script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).

Easier than assembling the script/batch file manually is to setup and test the connection settings in WinSCP GUI and then have it [generate the script or batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating):

[image: Generate batch file]

All you need to tweak is the source file name (use the `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax as shown previously) and the path to the log file.

---

For FTPS, replace the `sftp://` in the [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) with `ftpes://` ([explicit TLS/SSL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps#methods)) or `ftps://` ([implicit TLS/SSL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps#methods)). And remove the `-hostkey` switch.

```
winscp.com /log=ftpcmd.log /command ^
    "open ftps://ftp_user:password@ftp.MyFTPSite.com -explicit" ^
    "put c:\directory\%1-export-%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%.csv" ^
    "exit"
```

You may need to add the `-certificate` switch, if your server's certificate is [not issued by a trusted authority](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).

Again, as with the SFTP, easier is to setup and test the connection settings in WinSCP GUI and then have it [generate the script or batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

---

See a complete [conversion guide from `ftp.exe` to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

You should also read the [Guide to automating file transfers to FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

Note to using `%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%` instead of `%date%`: A format of `%date%` variable value is locale-specific. So make sure you test the script on the same locale you are actually going to use the script on. For example on my Czech locale the `%date%` resolves to `čt 06. 11. 2014`, what might be problematic when used as a part of a file name.

For this reason WinSCP supports [(locale-neutral) timestamp formatting natively](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp). For example `%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%` resolves to `20170515` on any locale.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 2):

The built in FTP command doesn't have a facility for security. Use [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se) instead. It's scriptable, far more robust and has FTP security.

Comment: Would WinSCP be a sufficient substitute, as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little code snippet in PowerShell to ease the call when WinSCP is not registered in the path but winscp.exe is available (default value points to the `Install-Module WinSCP` directory):

```
function Send-WinScpCommand ([string]$command, [string]$connection = "sftp://username:password@ftp.server.fr/", [string]$hostkey = "*", [string]$WinSCPDirectory = "$((Get-Module winscp).Path)\..\bin\") {
    Write-Host $command
    pushd; cd "$WinSCPDirectory"
    .\winscp.exe -loglevel=1 /log="C:\Temp\WinSCP.log" <#-console#> -command "open $connection -hostkey=$hostkey" "$command" "close" "exit" | Out-Null # Sync wait
    popd
}
```

Usage:

```
Send-WinScpCommand "get `"`"/ftpdir/distantfile.txt`"`" `"`"c:\temp\localfile.txt`"`""
Send-WinScpCommand "put `"`"c:\temp\localfile.txt`"`" `"`"/ftpdir/distantfile.txt`"`""
```

Original post answer using this function and sftp (my use case):
`Send-WinScpCommand "put c:\directory\%1-export-%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%.csv"`

---

As requested by @Stephan, a batch equivalent:

```
echo "%programfiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\WinSCP\6.1.2.0\bin\WinSCP.exe" -loglevel=1 /log="C:\Temp\WinSCP.log" -command "open sftp://username:password@ftp.server.fr -hostkey=*" %1 "close" "exit">Send-WinScpCommand.bat
```

Usage:

```
Send-WinScpCommand "get ""/ftpdir/distantfile.txt"" ""c:\temp\localfile.txt"""
Send-WinScpCommand "put ""c:\temp\localfile.txt"" ""/ftpdir/distantfile.txt"""
```

Comment: It's not tagged `cmd`, it's tagged `batch-file`. Though you're right (I've added the PowerShell mention in my answer), I'm editing to add a pure batch version.

Answer (score -2):

```
    ftps -a -z -e:on -pfxfile:"S-PID.p12" -pfxpwfile:"S-PID.p12.pwd" -user:<S-PID number> -s:script <RemoteServerName> 2121

S-PID.p12 => certificate file name ;
S-PID.p12.pwd => certificate password file name ; 
RemoteServerName =>  abcd123 ; 
2121 => port number ; 
ftps => command is part of ftps client software ;
```

Comment: Hi, Try to provide some context to your code, such as what it is doing and what software you are suggesting the OP uses.