# sftp from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, sftp

I need some files from unix server. So, I am making sftp connection with password from my windows 7 machine to unix server. but, now i want to include all these commands in batch file.
So, I need help on how should make sftp connection from batch file (basically, how to pass password to sftp prompt from batch file)?

Commands I am using:

```
> C:\Users\e578589>sftp

> server : TSEDCLVSAPPD116.svr.us.jpmchase.net

> user name : a_avatar

>a_avatar's Password:
/home/a_avatar>cd /data/ailsa/archive/open-loans-txns-to-bancs
/dev2/data/ailsa/archive/open-loans-txns-to-bancs> get {$FILENAME}
```

Comment: What is the `sftp`? Is it OpenSSH SFTP client?

Answer (score 0):

May be the following solution you can think for your unix/linus server as well.

[Secure FTP using Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150152/secure-ftp-using-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

How about **PSCP** - [PuTTY Download Page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)? It is easy to use in batch script.

```
pscp.exe -P PORT -pw PASSWORD USERNAME@IPADDRESS:SOURCE_PATH DEST_PATH
```

Perhaps you can use **PSFTP** ([PuTTY Download Page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) in the same way.