# Execute sftp commands on remote server using batch file and PuTTY

Tags: batch-file, sftp, putty

I have to transfer a file from one server to another. I log in to the first one with PuTTY and then type this:

```
sftp -v -oIdentityFile=path username@host 
cd path
put file
```

Everything works perfectly! Now I'm trying to do it with a batch file. In the .bat I have:

```
putty.exe -ssh host1 -l username1 -pw password1 -m script.txt
```

In the `script.txt` file:

```
sftp -v -oIdentityFile=path username2@host2
cd path
put file
exit
```

It connects to the server number two but then it stops. The prefix `sftp>` does not appear and it does not read the following lines. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150152/secure-ftp-using-windows-batch-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote shell takes the commands and executes them one by one. So it executes the `sftp`, waits for it to exit (what it never does) and only then it would execute the `cd` command (but in shell, not in the `sftp`), the `put` (failing as that's not a shell command), etc.

---

If your intention was to simulate typing the commands as on a terminal, use Plink and input redirection.

The [Plink (PuTTY command-line connection tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) is a tool from PuTTY package that works like PuTTY, but it is a console, not GUI, application. As such it can use input/output redirection. And anyway, the Plink is *the tool to automate tasks*, not PuTTY.

```
plink.exe -ssh host1 -l username1 -pw password1 < script.txt
```

For more details, see [How to type commands in PuTTY by creating batch file?](https://superuser.com/q/1103873/213663) on Super User.