# Batch File FTP over TLS

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp

I have a batch file that ftps a load of txt file across to a different server.

My Original batch file was as follows:

```
@echo off
echo user MyUser> ftpcmd.dat 
echo MyPassWord>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo lcd C:\MyFolder>>ftpcmd.dat 
echo mput *.txt>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat [ServerIP] 
del ftpcmd.dat 
del C:\MyFolder\*.txt
```

We are using Filezilla and when this runs we now get an error:

> This server does not allow plain FTP. You have to use FTP over TLS

Having found this post: [Secure FTP using Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150152/secure-ftp-using-windows-batch-script/34794955)

I updated the batch file to

```
@echo off
echo open ftpes://MyUser:MyPassword@[ServerIP] >> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd C:\MyFolder>>ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.txt>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat [SERVERIP]
del ftpcmd.dat
del C:\MyFolder\*.txt
```

This gives the errors:

> Already connected to [ServerIP], use disconnect first
>
> Please log in with USER and PASS first

I know I have lost my way somewhere and quite possibly misinterpreting the other post but I'm not sure quite what I'm doing wrong.
I don't think the two errors are related (although they may be) so I think the main question is

**How do I login with USER and PASS first?**

Comment: The first part of the error seems to imply you need to execute a specific `disconnect` command at the end of your script before quitting. I heard about that before; otherwise you need to wait for the connection to time out.

Comment: Windows `ftp.exe` DOES NOT support FTPS. You have to use a 3rd party FTP client (or PowerShell script). The [accepted answer to the question you have found yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151814/850848), shows how to use WinSCP (the `open ftpes://MyUser:MyPassword@[ServerIP]` is WinSCP syntax.)