# How can I make a batch based FTP connect via a port 22

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have this batch file which will be able to send files to my FTP. It logs in and everything but connects via the wrong port. Is there a way I can make this connect via port 22?
This FTP is with 000webhost

```
@echo off
CD %userprofile%/desktop
echo user MyUsername> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORDHERE>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat files.000webhost.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: Port 22 is normally reserved for sftp. Windows does not have a native sftp client.

Answer (score 1):

For an answer to your literal question, see:
[Cannot connect to non standard port number with Windows command-line ftp](https://superuser.com/q/1248499/213663).

---

Though, the port 22 is for SSH/SFTP. That has nothing to do with FTP, so you cannot use command-line `ftp`.

You have to use an SFTP client. See for example  [Secure FTP using Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16150152/850848). Also recent versions of Windows come with OpenSSH `sftp.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a alternative way for this. The **ftp** command has a subcommand **open**, and the open subcommand support specific port, Click [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490669.aspx). So you can put the subcommand **open** in your ftpcmd.dat file and open connect to your ftp server with a specific port via this subcommand.

For example, I did a test on my site, open ftp connect to a ftp server 172.18.128.122 with port 21, it works.

```
C:\>ftp -d -v -s:test.txt 127.0.0.1   #note, it is not ftp server ip here.
ftp> open 172.18.128.122 21           
Name(172.18.128.122:(none)):
---> USER test
---> PASS test
ftp> put aaa.txt
---> PORT 172,18,128,121,218,69
---> STOR aaa.txt
ftp> quit
---> QUIT
```

And my test.txt file is like below:

```
open 172.18.128.122 21
test
test
put aaa.txt
quit
```

So I think your bat file can be like below:

```
@echo off
CD %userprofile%/desktop
echo open files.000webhost.com 22> ftpcmd.dat
echo user MyUsername>> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORDHERE>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 127.0.0.1
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Hope it help, FYI.

Comment: I understand where the "-1" comes from: the port specification to `21` in the text file means the connection uses the standard Ftp port.
@Martin Prikryl's answer seems more on-point with a sftp port (actually using `22`).