# Windows CMD line 'sftp' authentication with a password

Tags: batch-file, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to automate file upload by creating .bat file which when run will upload files to SFTP server. I would like to automate this process, but `sftp` command line asks for password. Is there a way to enter the password in .bat file to automate it?

This is the code I'm using. It works, but user needs to enter the password. Is there a way to create batch file where password will be entered automatically?

```
sftp user@ip
password
put C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\* /public_html/upload
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit old, but
you can use [curl](https://curl.se/) to do it.

for example:

```
curl -T filename.ext sftp://sftpuser:sftppass@hostname/dir/
```

Answer (score -2):

I assume that you use (Win32-)OpenSSH [`sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp). It does not have any way to provide a password, on purpose.

- There are workarounds, covered for example in:
  [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)
  Though these use tools, which are not readily available on Windows.
- You should use a public key authentication instead.
- Or use another scriptable Windows SFTP client.
  See [Secure FTP using Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16150152/850848).

Comment: Links to answers don't really help anyone out. If this is a duplicate question it should be marked as such.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols I do not think it is duplicate. The other question is about Linux, this is about Windows. And this question is actually pretty broad (while the OP was understandably not aware of that). That's why I believe that a list of alternative solutions with links to details is a good way to answer to the question.